# How to convert UIColor value to a named color string?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

I need to convert `UIColor` to an `NSString` of the color name.

I tried:

```
 NSString *colorString = NSStringFromClass([[UIColor redColor] class]);
```

But `colorString` did not give @"redColor".

Comment: What format do you want the resulting NSString to have? What are you going to do with that string? (Display to user, save to file, ...)

Comment: hi, 
for example...whiteColor..
i want to convert it to string Data type.....@"whiteColor"...?

Comment: i want to convert into UTF8String..?any help..?

Comment: @JeffWood 4+ years later, but my answer below will return a named color -- e.g. "redColor" and not the RGB color components.

Answer (score 33):

The **`CIColor`** class contains color values and the color space for which the color values are valid.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicolor

```
// UIColor to NSString
CGColorRef colorRef = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;  
NSString *colorString = [CIColor colorWithCGColor:colorRef].stringRepresentation;
```

---

```
// NSString to UIColor 
CIColor *coreColor = [CIColor colorWithString:@"0.5 0.5 0.5 1.0"];  
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithCIColor:coreColor];
```

-----------------Warning-----------

If You Want Support All Devices The Way Mentioned Above to Convert NSString to UIColor Will Not Work On All Devices.

---

**stringRepresentation**

Returns a formatted string that specifies the components of the color.

The string representation always has four components—red, green, blue, and alpha.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicolor/1437910-stringrepresentation

---

**colorWithString:**

Creates a color object using the RGBA color component values specified by a string.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicolor/1438059-colorwithstring

Comment: Not sure why this answer has so many upvotes. It's incorrect. `stringRepresentation` returns a formatted string with the components of the color, not the color name which is what the OP asked for.

Comment: He gave two examples, `colorString did not give @"redColor"` and `for example...whiteColor`.

Answer (score 17):

```
UIColor *color = value;
const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor);
NSString *colorAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f,%f,%f", components[0], components[1], components[2], components[3]];
```

Done.

If you want to convert the string back to a UIColor object:

```
NSArray *components = [colorAsString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
CGFloat r = [[components objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
CGFloat g = [[components objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
CGFloat b = [[components objectAtIndex:2] floatValue];
CGFloat a = [[components objectAtIndex:3] floatValue];
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:a];
```

Are you storing a UIColor object as an attribute in Core Data? If so, check out my answer to this question: [Core Data data model: attribute type for UIColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304882/core-data-data-model-attribute-type-for-uicolor/3172363#3172363)

Comment: Any info on how to convert this string back to uicolor ? :)

Answer (score 10):

What do you want to do that for? Have a look at generic `-desciption` method for a start

```
UIColor* someColor = ...//Initialize color
NSString* colorString = [someColor description];
```

Comment: This solution works great in the XCode debugger (as of XCode 4.6.3).

Comment: Does not work gives RGBa instead `Color I am going to use is--> UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1`

Comment: you get a debug string. not the string value of the color

Answer (score 7):

Try this . Best solution for my problem.Might help you guys also..

https://github.com/daniel-beard/DBColorNames

Comment: This is an incredible find, and if the name of the color is what the OP is asking for, perhaps this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer. If you want a user-facing description of a color, this is the way to go.

Comment: This was the most helpful solution.

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
- (NSString *)stringForColor:(UIColor *)color {
    CGColorRef c = color.CGColor;
    const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(c);
    size_t numberOfComponents = CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(c);
    NSMutableString *s = [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease];
    [s appendString:@"{"];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numberOfComponents; ++i) {
        if (i > 0) {
            [s appendString:@","];
        }
        [s appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", components[i]]];
    }
    [s appendString:@"}"];
    return s;
}
```

For example, `stringForColor:[UIColor greenColor]` has the result "{0.000000,1.000000,0.000000,1.000000}".

Comment: Actually, -description returns the same + Color space information

Comment: Yes, but -description also includes the class name, which may or may not be desirable (questioner doesn't say what he wants the string to look like).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I used to convert from CGColor to NSString #RRGGBBAA format:

```
// Return the parsed core graphics color as a "#RRGGBBAA" string value

+ (NSString*) cgColorToString:(CGColorRef)cgColorRef
{
  const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(cgColorRef);
  int red = (int)(components[0] * 255);
  int green = (int)(components[1] * 255);
  int blue = (int)(components[2] * 255);
  int alpha = (int)(components[3] * 255);
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#%0.2X%0.2X%0.2X%0.2X", red, green, blue, alpha];
}
```

Comment: be careful with this because it's assuming the color is in the RGB colorspace, which is not necessarily the case. For example, UIColor.Black.CGColor is in the gray colorspace and only has two components (intensity and alpha).

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest way to convert UIColor to NSString:

```
- (NSString *)stringFromColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    const size_t totalComponents = CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(color.CGColor);
    const CGFloat * components = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor);
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#%02X%02X%02X",
            (int)(255 * components[MIN(0,totalComponents-2)]),
            (int)(255 * components[MIN(1,totalComponents-2)]),
            (int)(255 * components[MIN(2,totalComponents-2)])];
}
```

Comment: There is a comma missing on the second-to-last line.