# Core Data data model: attribute type for UIColor

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

I'm just starting out with Core Data and right now I'm building my data model. I need a UIColor attribute for my entity, but the type dropdown for the attribute doesn't have an option for this. Do I set it to Undefined or what?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you probably want is a transformable attribute. Give the section on "[Non-standard Persistent Attributes](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001919-SW1)" in the Core Data Programming Guide an other read. A transformable attribute is, underneath the covers, a binary data attribute, but Core Data will automatically use the `NSValueTransformer` of your specification to serialize and unserialize the logical attribute value for you. For values that are `NSCoding` compliant, the `NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName` (which is the default transformer) will do the trick.

Of course, Core Data cannot index or, for an SQLite backend, query against this transformable value.

Answer (score 21):

I'll paraphrase the definitve answer I found in *More iPhone 3 Development* by Dave Mark and Jeff LeMarche:

**Usually we'd be able to leave the transformable attribute's transformer class as the default, *NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData*, and be done, but in this case we can't because `UIColor` doesn't conform to `NSCoding`** and can't be archived using an `NSKeyedArchiver`. We have to manually write a value transformer to handle the transformation.

Add an attribute to your entity and call the attribute "color", or whatever name you wish. Set its type to *Transformable*. Set its "Value Transformer Name" to *UIColorRGBValueTransformer*. Note that the data model editor doesn't validate the *Value Transformer Name:* to make sure it's a valid class, so type carefully.

Create a new file, a subclass of `NSObject`, and name it *UIColorRGBValueTransformer.m*.

Click *UIColorRGBValueTransformer.h* and change the superclass from NSObject to NSValueTransformer. Also, change `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` to `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`, since `UIColor` is part of `UIKit`, not `Foundation`.

Now in *UIColorRGBValueTransformer.m*, we need to implement four methods that allow our value transformer class to convert instances of `UIColor` to `NSData` and vice versa. Include the following code in *UIColorRGBValueTransformer.m*:

```
#import "UIColorRGBValueTransformer.h"

@implementation UIColorRGBValueTransformer

// Here we override the method that returns the class of objects that this transformer can convert.
+ (Class)transformedValueClass {
    return [NSData class];
}

// Here we indicate that our converter supports two-way conversions.
// That is, we need  to convert UICOLOR to an instance of NSData and back from an instance of NSData to an instance of UIColor.
// Otherwise, we wouldn't be able to beth save and retrieve values from the persistent store.
+ (BOOL)allowsReversTransformation {
    return YES;
}

// Takes a UIColor, returns an NSData
- (id)transfomedValue:(id)value {
    UIColor *color = value;
    const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor);
    NSString *colorAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f,%f,%f", components[0], components[1], components[2], components[3]];
    return [colorAsString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

// Takes an NSData, returns a UIColor
- (id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value {
    NSString *colorAsString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:value encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
    NSArray *components = [colorAsString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    CGFloat r = [[components objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
    CGFloat g = [[components objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
    CGFloat b = [[components objectAtIndex:2] floatValue];
    CGFloat a = [[components objectAtIndex:3] floatValue];
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:a];
}

@end
```

Now in another file, you can include a line of code like:

```
[self.managedObject setValue:color forKey:self.keyPath];
```

without needing to import *UIColorRGBValueTransformer.h* in the file.

Comment: This answer is amazing, never would have figured this out. One tiny edit, "allowsReversTransformation" and "transfomedValue" are misspelled but fixing only account for 2 of a required 6 letters worth of edits.

Comment: Although this did work for it should be noted that UIColor actually does conform to NSCoding (contrary to what is noted above) and a special transformer shouldn't be required.

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible to store the UIColor as a String as a HEX (FFFFFF, or other web-safe colors) and then when you come to read the color, you convert the string into a format that UIColor can understand?

Answer (score 3):

After specify color attribute as transformable with name ColorToDataTransformer.
We can simply generate MangatedObjectSubclass and write transformer code inside it

//SampleEntity.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
@interface SampleEntity : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor *color;
@end

@interface ColorToDataTransformer : NSValueTransformer
@end
```

//SampleEntity.m

```
#import "SampleEntity.h"

@implementation SampleEntity

@dynamic color;

@end

@implementation ColorToDataTransformer

+ (BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation {
    return YES;
}

+ (Class)transformedValueClass {
    return [NSData class];
}


- (id)transformedValue:(id)value {
    UIColor *color = (UIColor *)value;
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:color];
    return data;
}

- (id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value {
    NSData *data = (NSData *)value;
    UIColor *color = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
    return color;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is a Swift's Version of @RosePerrone answers.
I Hope it helps.

```
class ColorToDataTransformer: ValueTransformer {

// Here we indicate that our converter supports two-way conversions.
// That is, we need  to convert UICOLOR to an instance of NSData and back from an instance of NSData to an instance of UIColor.
// Otherwise, we wouldn't be able to beth save and retrieve values from the persistent store.
override class func allowsReverseTransformation() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override class func transformedValueClass() -> AnyClass {
    return NSData.self
}

// Takes a UIColor, returns an NSData
override func transformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
    guard let color = value as? UIColor else { return nil }

    guard let components: [CGFloat] = color.cgColor.components else { return nil }

    let colorAsString: String = String(format: "%f,%f,%f,%f", components[0], components[1], components[2], components[3])

    return colorAsString.data(using: .utf8)
}

// Takes an NSData, returns a UIColor
override func reverseTransformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
    guard let data = value as? Data else { return nil }

    guard let colorAsString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else { return nil }

    let componets: [String] = colorAsString.components(separatedBy: ",")

    var values: [Float] = []

    for component in componets {
        guard let value = Float(component) else { return nil }
        values.append(value)
    }

    let red: CGFloat = CGFloat(values[0])
    let green: CGFloat = CGFloat(values[1])
    let blue: CGFloat = CGFloat(values[2])
    let alpha: CGFloat = CGFloat(values[3])

   return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
}
```

}