# Create UIColor from NSColor Data

Tags: iphone, cocoa, core-data, uikit

I have a CoreData Mac app for which I'm writing an iOS front end.  All's working well thusfar, I'm able to successfully read files created with the Mac app in the iOS version.  I'm struggling with how to read the NSColor data (being stored as an NSData object in my data model) into a UIColor in iOS version of the app.

To summarize: How do take an NSData object containing an archived NSColor object and convert it to the appropriate UIColor object on an iOS device?

Comment: As noted by Dave DeLong, you won't be able to unarchive to an NSColor object on the iOS side of things. That being the case, you may want to serialize the components (as an NSArray, for example) or create a custom class that both platforms can understand.

Comment: warrenm has the right answer.  You're going to have to do not use `NSColor`/`UIColor` directly.  You can create your own `NSObject` subclass with RGBA components and archive that, or just archive the values directly.

Comment: Agreed.  Implementing this would require some substantial changes to shipping Mac OS code so I'm reluctant to jump on that now but I'll tackle it on the next revision and plan the iOS version around that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What I've done thus far (and it works, but isn't pretty) is to read the NSData into an NSString (the data seems to be ASCII encoded).  The RGB values are present in the NSString and with a little parsing can be extracted to create a new UIColor.

I'm not sure if this is a global solution or one that happens to work in my case, but it's a start.

It would obviously be better to serialize as an NSArray and I'll look into that for the future.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following from the [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001919-SW2)

Have you tried replacing `NSColor` with `UIColor`? `UIColor` implements the `NSCoding` protocol

```
// - (NSColor *)color
- (UIColor *)color
{

    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"color"];

    // NSColor *color = [self primitiveColor];
    UIColor *color = [self primitiveColor];

    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"color"];

     if (color == nil)

    {

        NSData *colorData = [self colorData];

        if (colorData != nil)

        {

            color = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:colorData];                

            [self setPrimitiveColor:color];

        }

    }

    return color;

}
```

Comment: As best I can tell, this fails because UIKit is unable to unarchive and decode an object of Class NSColor.

Comment: Ok then. Takea look at this SO question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304882/core-data-data-model-attribute-type-for-uicolor

Comment: Perhaps I'm reading this wrong, but your linked question seems to show how to serialize and store a UIColor.  This isn't my issue.  I've got a serialized NSColor and I need to read it into a UIColor.  

Also, UIColor doesn't conform to NSCoder as stated in your answer...Thanks for the help though. This is really the only trouble spot I'm having reading a Mac OS Coredata file on iOS. Thus far.

Comment: According to the docs UIColor conforms to the NSCoding protocol.  http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html. Do you have a sample NSColor that you want to have instantiated as a UIColor?