# How to save a specific NSLocale in CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data, nslocale

Trying to save Locales into CoreData and just wasn't sure what format I should save the data.

```
let locale = Locale.current
let currencyCodesArray = Locale.commonISOCurrencyCodes

for currencyCode in currencyCodesArray {

        // let currencyName = locale.displayName(forKey:NSLocale.Key.currencyCode, value : currencyCode)
        let currencyName = locale.localizedString(forCurrencyCode: currencyCode)

        //let currencySymbol = locale.displayName(forKey:NSLocale.Key.currencySymbol, value : currencyCode)
        let currencySymbol = locale.currencySymbol

        let identifier = locale.localizedString(forIdentifier: currencyCode)

         print(identifier);

        if let _ = currencySymbol, let currencyName = currencyName{

            let currencyModel = CurrencyModel()
            currencyModel.currencyName = currencyName
            currencyModel.currencyCode = currencyCode
            currencyModel.currencySymbol = currencySymbol!

            //currencyModel.identifier = identifier

            currencies.append(currencyModel)

            //print(identifier);
        }
    }
```

From each locale I'm trying to save:
currency code - string
Identifier - String
currency name - String
currency symbol - String

Should I be saving each of these properties on their own, or is it possible to save the entire Locale?

Answer (score 1):

In Swift it's `Locale` without `NS` and without bridge cast

```
let locale = Locale.current
```

Save the `identifier` of the `Locale` which is a `String`

```
let currentIdentifier = Locale.current.identifer
```

And create a `Locale` when reading it

```
let locale = Locale(identifier : currentIdentifier)
```

Comment: No, they are different.

Comment: I'm trying to save the identifier for whichever currency the user selects, but right now it only seems to be using my local identifier. I've updated my code above. I think its the line that should be something else: currencyModel.identifier = locale.localeIdentifier

Comment: Please stop using `NSLocale`. Use the native Swift struct.

Comment: What would that look like? When I type it out, code hinting gives me the NSLocale version. Made some updates. One of the issues I'm running into is there doesn't seem to be a displayName property on the Swift Locale.

Comment: You can use also the `localizedString(for...` methods.

Comment: am I on the right path with what I'm doing in the updated code?

Comment: I tried to use this: let identifier = locale.localizedString(forIdentifier: currencyCode) but it returns a bunch of nils and a few actual indetifiers

Answer (score 0):

You can save NSLocale as [Transformable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsattributetype/transformableattributetype) attribute.

[NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299499/using-an-nsvaluetransformer-to-set-values-of-an-nsmanagedobject-instance) is used by default to transform your plain object to Core Data storage representation. But in this case your plain object should conform [NSCoding](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscoding) or [NSSecureCoding](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nssecurecoding) protocol.

If you want to transform more complex object you have to subclass [NSValueTransformer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsvaluetransformer).

But NSLocale conforms to NSSecureCoding so you can save it directly by setting type of this attribute of your Entity to Transformable.

See the [sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/PhotoLocations/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008909-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) from Apple.

Comment: I updated my question and code, am I creating the array of locales incorrectly?