# How do i call class method dynamically in IOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uicolor

I'm stuck with a problem here in `UIColor`.

I'll be getting color names from webservices like

> Red, Blue, Magenta .......  and so.

how can i set the backgroundColor of a view using this.

i can only find class methods with these color names (`[UIColor redColor], [UIColor blueColor], [UIColor magentaColor]`) but i'm not able to write a code which programatically calls these methods cause the color names i get are dynamic.

PLease Help.....

Thank you.

Comment: Please check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748350/how-to-convert-uicolor-value-to-nsstring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Key Value Coding mechanism allows you to interact with class's properties using string representations of the property names.

```
NSString* colorString = @"redColor";
UIColor* color = [UIColor valueForKey:colorString];
```

Comment: @PrateekRaj it would work but not fully optimise Solution dude, suppose if you got some colorName form service which is not exist in `UIColor class` then in that case you could not show that color.

Answer (score 8):

Something like this should work:

```
NSString *colorFromWeb = @"Red"; // for example
NSString *selectorName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Color", [colorFromWeb lowercaseString]];
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(selectorName);

if ([UIColor respondsToSelector:selector])
    UIColor *color = [UIColor performSelector:selector]; // Equivalent to [UIColor redColor];
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you can Follow Two Approach.

**1)**.Here you can make the call to the `color` Method by passing the Name of these coming Colors.

As `Scott` explain in his Answer.

```
  NSString *colorFromWeb = @"Red"; // for example
  NSString *selectorName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Color", [colorFromWeb lowercaseString]];
  SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(selectorName);

  if ([UIColor respondsToSelector:selector])
  UIColor *color = [UIColor performSelector:selector]; // Equivalent to [UIColor redColor];
```

**2)**.In Above way you may face some trouble suppose you got some `color` name form Your `WebService` which is not exist in `UIColor Class` then in that case you can not get that **desirable color or might be your app could crashed etc.**
Here I would Suggest you you should ask the `RGB float` Values From your `Webservice Provider`.In this way You can easily pass These `RGB` and can make `Color` with these `RGB`

Here is Some Demo.

```
 [UIColor colorWithRed:redRGB green:greenRGB blue:blueRGB alpha:1.0];
```

You just need to obtain  `redRGB`,`greenRGB`and `blueRGB` from WebService.
In this You can' face any `Crash`.

I hope It may clears To you.

Comment: The respondsToSelector check ensures that any value passed in from the web service does in fact translate to a valid selector.

Comment: @Scott i know Scott i just missed that single line dude... i gonna edit my answer..well what do you think about my approach ..

Comment: It's an option as well, but it requires the web service to return a float as opposed to a string. If that's not an option (because you don't own the web service, for example), then you're out of luck.

Comment: @Scott yes scott you again right, but think if `PrateekRaj`got some color which is not exist in `UIColor` class. can he use that color?.