# Objective C UIColor to NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, nsstring, uicolor

I need to convert a UIColor to an NSString with the name of the color i.e.

```
[UIColor redColor];
```

should become

```
@"RedColor"
```

I've already tried`[UIColor redColor].CIColor.stringRepresentation`
but it causes a compiler error

Comment: See the top-rated answer here; it may assist: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748350/how-to-convert-uicolor-value-to-nsstring

Comment: You can't do what you want without writing your own method. The answers people are pointing you to are going to give you something like "1 0 0 1" or "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1".

Comment: How do you want to get this color name -- that is, how are you going to use it?

Answer (score 9):

Just expanding on the answer that @Luke linked to which creates a CGColorRef to pass to CIColor:

```
CGColorRef colorRef = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
```

You could instead simply pass the CGColor property of the UIColor you're working on like:

```
NSString *colorString = [[CIColor colorWithCGColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]] stringRepresentation];
```

Don't forget to import the Core Image framework.

Side note, a quick and easy way to convert back to a UIColor from the string could be something like this:

```
NSArray *parts = [colorString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
UIColor *colorFromString = [UIColor colorWithRed:[parts[0] floatValue] green:[parts[1] floatValue] blue:[parts[2] floatValue] alpha:[parts[3] floatValue]];
```

Comment: This will not give him "GrayColor" which is what he asked for.

Comment: I tried both this and the link but both of them returned the rgb+alpha equivalent. I want to know the name of the color so [uicolor whitecolor] would return white NOT 1 1 1 1

Answer (score 2):

This is the shortest way to convert UIColor to NSString:

```
- (NSString *)stringFromColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    const size_t totalComponents = CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(color.CGColor);
    const CGFloat * components = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor);
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#%02X%02X%02X",
            (int)(255 * components[MIN(0,totalComponents-2)]),
            (int)(255 * components[MIN(1,totalComponents-2)]),
            (int)(255 * components[MIN(2,totalComponents-2)])];
}
```