# ios8 Swift - Converting UIColor

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, uicolor

Is there any way to convert a UIColor to a string?
For example,

```
var color = UIColor.purpleColor()
var colorString : String = //Purple
```

If you can help me it would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can get color description

```
var color = UIColor.purpleColor()
var colorString : String = color.description
println(colorString)
```

---

```
var cgColorRef = UIColor.purpleColor().CGColor
var strColor = CIColor(CGColor: cgColorRef).stringRepresentation()
println(strColor)
```

Reference from : [How to convert UIColor value to a named color string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748350/how-to-convert-uicolor-value-to-a-named-color-string)