# How to set a default NSUserDefaults value for a UIColor in a plist file?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, uicolor

I have a very basic class that contains for a dashboard item that contains a title (string) and a color (UIColor).

The values are encoded/decoded via the following methods:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.title = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("title") as! String
    self.color = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("color") as! UIColor
}

func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(self.title, forKey: "title")
    aCoder.encodeObject(self.color, forKey: "color")
}
```

... and accessed / persisted via the following functions:

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as! [DashboardItem]


NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self.dashboardItems), forKey: DASHBOARD_SCREENS)
```

*Aside: The idea being that users can create a custom dashboard that will allow them to edit the title, color and various other values of a dashboard item.*

I have created a `UserDefaults.plist` file will contain the default values for the app, **but I am unsure of how to set a default value for a UIColor?**

In addition to this, I am not entirely sure if my plist structure is correct. I am assuming that the structure of the user defaults should contain a dictionary (root) of defaults where DASHBOARD_SCREENS is an array of DashboardItem, should this be a dictionary?

[image: User defaults plist structure]

Thanks in advance

edit:

Swift `v2.2`

XCode `v7.3.1`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748350/how-to-convert-uicolor-value-to-a-named-color-string  In this answer you can see, color can be converted into some string. you can do like thta

Comment: The answer to the linked question is not good for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try up a different approach like saving the RGB value of colour in UserDefaults instead, Just add this extension of UIColor:

#### Swift 3

```
extension UIColor {

    //MARK:- Properties
    var redValue: CGFloat{ return CIColor(color: self).red }
    var greenValue: CGFloat{ return CIColor(color: self).green }
    var blueValue: CGFloat{ return CIColor(color: self).blue }
    var alphaValue: CGFloat{ return CIColor(color: self).alpha }
}
```

And these methods to convert UIColor value to String and Vice-Versa:

```
func getColor(color : UIColor) -> String {

    let redComponent = color.redValue
    let greenComponent = color.greenValue
    let blueComponent = color.blueValue
    let alpha = color.alphaValue
    let colorString = String(describing: redComponent) + ":" + String(describing: greenComponent) + ":" + String(describing: blueComponent) + ":" + String(describing: alpha)

    return colorString
}


func setColor(colorString : String) -> UIColor {

    let colorComponents = colorString.components(separatedBy: ":")
    let redComponent = (colorComponents[0] as NSString).floatValue
    let greenComponent = (colorComponents[1] as NSString).floatValue
    let blueComponent = (colorComponents[2] as NSString).floatValue
    let alpha = (colorComponents[3] as NSString).floatValue

    return UIColor(colorLiteralRed: redComponent, green: greenComponent, blue: blueComponent, alpha: alpha)
}
```

Now use this string value to store in NSUserDefaults and Took this string value out and Change back to UIColor by calling setColor method.

#### Swift 2

```
extension UIColor {

    //MARK:- Properties
    var redValue: CGFloat { return CGColorGetComponents(self.CGColor)[0] }
    var greenValue: CGFloat { return CGColorGetComponents(self.CGColor)[1] }
    var blueValue: CGFloat { return CGColorGetComponents(self.CGColor)[2] }
    var alphaValue: CGFloat { return CGColorGetComponents(self.CGColor)[3] }
}

func getColor(color : UIColor) -> String {

    let redComponent = color.redValue
    let greenComponent = color.greenValue
    let blueComponent = color.blueValue
    let alpha = color.alphaValue

    let colorString = String(redComponent) + ":" + String(greenComponent) + ":" + String(blueComponent) + ":" + String(alpha)

    return colorString
}

func setColor(colorString : String) -> UIColor {

    let colorComponents = colorString.componentsSeparatedByString(":")
    let redComponent = (colorComponents[0] as NSString).floatValue
    let greenComponent = (colorComponents[1] as NSString).floatValue
    let blueComponent = (colorComponents[2] as NSString).floatValue
    let alpha = (colorComponents[3] as NSString).floatValue

    return UIColor(colorLiteralRed: redComponent, green: greenComponent, blue: blueComponent, alpha: alpha)
}
```

Comment: This could work. However, I forgot to mention that I am using Swift 2.2 (Sorry!) do you know what the equivalent of `CIColor(color: self).{red|green|blue|alpha}` is for 2.2?

Comment: FYI - Swift 2 implementation looks like:

`let {red|green|blue|alpha}: CGFloat{ return CGColorGetComponents(self.CGColor)[{0|1|2|3}] }`

@Himanshu may be worth updating your original answer as it may help others find the relevant answer quicker :)

Comment: I haven't actually see which swift version you are using.

Comment: no problem! It's my fault I did not put the version in the original question.

Comment: Okay, keep swifting.