# backgroundColor name not being displayed properly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am new to iOS programming and am currently doing an Intro to xCode and Swift 3 tutorial. In the exercise, we need to retreive the background color of the view and display the **NAME** of the color in a label.

I am getting the strange text `UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 1 1 1` in the label instead of the Views color’s name (red, green, etc). I suspect I haven’t unwrapped an optional in the right way.

Here is optional property variable declaration in the ViewController class.

```
//View Controller class
var labelColor: UILabel!
```

Here is the code in the viewDidLoad function for displaying the backgroundColor's name:

```
    //LabelColor.  
    let labelColor = UILabel()
    labelColor.frame = CGRect(x:10, y:50, width:300, height:60)
    labelColor.font = labelColor.font.withSize(10)
    labelColor.text = String(describing: self.view.backgroundColor)
    ... 
    self.view.addSubview(labelColor)
    self.labelColor = labelColor 
    …
```

The backgroundColor of the view is set and updated in another part of the code.

Why am I getting the text `UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 1 1 1` in this label, instead of the actual background color?

Comment: A `UIColor` does not know what its name is. It only knows how much red, green, blue and alpha it has, which is what the 4 `1`s you get represent. You have to write if statements to check whether the color is `.red`, `.green` or something else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert UIColor value to a named color string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748350/how-to-convert-uicolor-value-to-a-named-color-string)

Comment: Is the color white ??

Comment: The color is randomly set by a separate function. Could be any color, including white.  I just want the name of the view's background color to appear in the label. Should be possible.

Comment: I found this, and it helped me:  https://github.com/daniel-beard/DBColorNames.